# How to get href element with selector?

Tags: android, jsoup

I am using this to get items from this website and return to a list.

```
  Document doc = null;
    try {
        doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.gamespy.com/index/release.html").get();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
        // Get all td's that are a child of a row - each game has 4 of these
        Elements games = doc.select("tr>  td.indexList1, tr > td.indexList2");

        // Iterator over those elements     
        ListIterator<Element> postIt = games.listIterator();          
        while (postIt.hasNext()) {     
            // ...It 

            while (postIt.hasNext()) {     
                // Add the game text to the ArrayList     
                String name = postIt.next().text();
                String platform = postIt.next().text();
                String genre = postIt.next().text();
                String releaseDate = postIt.next().text();
                gameList.add(new GameRelease(name, platform, genre, releaseDate));
                Log.v(TAG, name +platform + genre +releaseDate);
            }
```

This is the html for the each item

```
<tr>
<td class="indexList1" align="left">
  <a href="http://pc.gamespy.com/pc/hacker-evolution-duality-/" class="b1">  
    <em>Hacker Evolution Duality </em>
  </a>
</td>
<td class="indexList1" align="center">
  PC 
</td>    
<td class="indexList1" align="center">

  Adventure 
</td>
<td class="indexList1" align="center">
    August 15, 2011
    <!--08/15/2011-->
</td>
```

Each item has the same pattern but i want to know could i retreive the url for each item too. You guys may need to view the source of the html too get a better idea.

But i want to store the url for each item in a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while (postIt.hasNext()) {
    // Get the title of the game
    Element title = postIt.next();

    System.out.println(title.text());

    // Get the anchor element
    Element url = title.select("a").first();

    // Get the URL here @@@
    System.out.println(url.attr("href"));

    // Unneeded elements
    Element platform = postIt.next();
    Element genre = postIt.next();

    // Get the release date of the game
    Element release = postIt.next();
    System.out.println(release.text() + "\n@@@@@@");
}
```

EDIT:  In your case:

```
Element name = postIt.next();
String nameString = name.text();

Element url = name.select("a").first();
String urlString = url.attr("href");
```

Answer (score 1):

> Each item has the same pattern but i want to know could i retreive the url for each item too.

```
Elements links = doc.getElementsByTag("a"); // or getElementsByClass("b1");

ListIterator<Element> postIt = games.listIterator();          
    while (postIt.hasNext()) {
        String linkHref = link.attr("href");
    }
}
```

Comment: So will it get it for each item? seperately?

Comment: Couldnt i just use Elements games?

Comment: And where did you get content from?

Comment: sorry - content should be "doc".

Comment: And yes, perhaps there is a better way but my advice should guide you in the right direction.

Comment: The "a" only returns www.ign.com/ "b1" doesnt return anything

Comment: @citizenconn let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2505/discussion-between-coder-for-life22-and-citizen-conn)